# How to convert String to math expression and evaluate using a variable?

Tags: java, math

So I know that you can use

```
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String infix = "3+2*(4+5)";
    System.out.println(engine.eval(infix));
```

which is all great but what if I wanted to evaluate a variable in that expression call it x and make that a random variable between 0 and 1. This is an idea to evaluate definite integrals using a monte carlo method by using input given by the user. So if we had something like say

```
    String infix = x^2+2;
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: clearly state your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`ScriptEngine#put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) to set the respective variable. E.g.:

```
...
engine.put("x", 25);
System.out.println(engine.eval("x * x + 3 * x + 5"));
```

Alternatively you could make use of the fact that the context of the ScriptEngine isn't switched between two `eval`-calls:

```
...
engine.eval("var x = 25");
System.out.println(engine.eval("x * x + 3 * x + 5"));
```

Comment: @jc7553a glad to help :). If the answer solved your problem consider accepting it (the tick next to the up-/downvote arrows) to mark the problem as solved ;)